# How to change Woocommerce currency symbol

Tags: php, woocommerce

my Woocommerce is having toubles to send feeds to Amazon SellerCentral.
Amazon requires EUR as woocommerce_currency value but Woocommerce returns €.
How can I change this value?
Thanks a lot.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 
10, 2);

function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
 switch( $currency ) {
      case 'EUR': $currency_symbol = 'EUR'; break;
 }
 return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Comment: Don you need to convert the currency rate as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would able to make your custom currency, which one will show on the backend currency selection drop down.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'add_cw_currency' );
function add_cw_currency( $cw_currency ) {
     $cw_currency['CLOUDWAYS'] = __( 'CLOUDWAYS CURRECY', 'woocommerce' );
     return $cw_currency;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_cw_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
function add_cw_currency_symbol( $custom_currency_symbol, $custom_currency ) {
     switch( $custom_currency ) {
         case 'CLOUDWAYS': $custom_currency_symbol = 'CW$'; break;
     }
     return $custom_currency_symbol;
}
```

There are little explanation with following link, hope that one could help you. 
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-currency-symbol-in-woocommerce/

thanks !

Comment: It's change currency- That will affect store. OP needs change symbol only

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_my_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function add_my_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'USD': $currency_symbol = 'EUR >>'; break;
          //case 'EUR': $currency_symbol = 'EUR'; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Creating a child theme for the current theme can be the solution but I think you don't have to do that much if you only want to change the symbol, simply go in the woocommerce backend files: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php`

If you don't have a backend file excess download file manager in your wordpress theme you will see these folders in you main site.

wp-content >> plugins >> woocommerce >> includes >> wc-core-functions.php

In wc-core-function.php file you will see the symbol:

[image]