# Changing symbol and format for specific currency

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, currency

I have two currencies; USD and SWC (which is a custom points based currency).
Woocommerce allows me to set a default currency, decimal and symbol position which applies to both however I'd like to customise the decimals and the symbol position.

The following (from [How to change Woocommerce currency symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876228/how-to-change-woocommerce-currency-symbol)) works for customising the symbol.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'SWC': $currency_symbol = 'SWC$'; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```

How do I also set the decimals (to zero) and the position (to be on the right) please?

Tried [How to change Woocommerce currency symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876228/how-to-change-woocommerce-currency-symbol)